# Which API to use to access location history for an android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am making an app which stores most travelled routes and uses it for other actions. I need to access Google Maps location history. Which API should I use to have access to Google Maps' Location History.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there's no Google API to access location history. However, you can [access location](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3118687?hl=en) history externally. Your location history allows Google to show you useful information based on where you’ve been with the devices that you’re signed in to with your Google Account. Some of this information applies to Android devices running Android 4.4 or higher. Learn how to [manage location access](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819558) in Android 4.1 to Android 4.3.

You can turn location mode on or off completely, or just change your device's location accuracy mode. Each mode uses different sources to estimate your device’s location.

To control what location information your device can use, follow these steps:

- On your mobile device, open the Settings menu Settings.
- Under "Personal," touch **Location access**.
- When the **Access to my location** switch at the top of the screen is *On*, you can select either or both of these checkboxes:

  1. **GPS satellites**: Just like a GPS device in your car, lets your device calculate your location based on satellite signals.
  2. **Wi-Fi & mobile network location**: Lets your device use Google's location service to help estimate your location faster, with or without help from GPS.
- When the switch is **Off**, your device can’t find your precise location or share it with any apps.